# CSLA How to create Info Classes with child-parent relationships

Tags: c#, csla

I'm new to CSLA, so I'm trying to figure out how to solve the following problem.I want to write 4 info classes, like these on the following diagram.
[image]

They are all info classes, DayRecordInfoCollection is collection of DayRecordInfo objects, and DayRecord can have more activities, so it is parent to ActivityRecordCollectionInfo , which is collection of ActivityRecordInfo.
Also, DayRecordInfo has 3 properties , Id, StartTime, EndTime, and ActivityRecordInfo has 4 properties  , Id, IdDayRecord, StartTime, EndTime.
[image]

So far I've created 4 basic structured Info classe

-`public class DayRecordInfo : ReadOnlyBase<DayRecordInfo>`

-`public class DayRecordInfoCollection : ReadOnlyBindingListBase<DayRecordInfoCollection,DayRecordInfo>`

-`public class ActivityRecordInfoCollection : ReadOnlyBindingListBase<ActivityRecordInfoCollection,ActivityRecordInfo>`

-`public class ActivityRecordInfo : ReadOnlyBase<ActivityRecordInfo>`

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to link them with FieldManager.
I thought of creating property inside DayRecordInfo like this

```
public static readonly PropertyInfo<ActivityRecordInfoCollection> ActivitiesProperty = RegisterProperty<ActivityRecordInfoCollection>(c => c.Activities);
    public ActivityRecordInfoCollection Activities
    {
        get 
        {
            if (!(FieldManager.FieldExists(ActivitiesProperty)))
            {
                LoadProperty(ActivitiesProperty, DataPortal.CreateChild<ActivityRecordInfoCollection>());
            }
            return GetProperty(ActivitiesProperty);
        }
        private set { LoadProperty(ActivitiesProperty, value); }
    }
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are code snippets in the \Support\Snippets folder that demonstrate how to define child properties for sync or async loading.

https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/tree/master/Support/Snippets